# Windows 10 creating files and directories on Ubuntu 20.04 Samba share

Tags: samba, windows-10

I installed Samba on Ubuntu 20.04 and have the following `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        server role = standalone server
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        workgroup = MYDOMAIN
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
        browseable = No
        comment = All Printers
        create mask = 0700
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[myuser]
        comment = My drive
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0777
        path = /data/myuser
        read only = No
```

Whenever I create a directory from Windows 10, the permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 myuser mydomain       4096 Aug 11 11:07 test2
```

I tried editing `smb.conf` to remove `create mask` and `directory mask` lines. I then restarted Samba, but the permissions are still the same:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 myuser mydomain       4096 Aug 11 11:16 test3
```

I need the permissions to be at least `drwxrwxr-x`

I've gone through multiple websites, with different recommendations:
`create mask = 0666`, `create mask = 0664`, all kinds of directory masks. It seems I can create stricter permissions with "create mask", but what I want are looser permissions.

Comment: What is the file system of the volume? File systems used by Windows are not capable of POSIX ownership and permissions.

Comment: The filesystem is EXT4.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely permissions perspective:

I took an existing public share and added two lines to modify the resulting permissions on saved files:

```
[Public]
    create mask = 0664
    force directory mode = 0775
    force user = tester
    guest ok = Yes
    path = /srv/Public
    read only = No
```

I then created a file and a directory from Win10. This is the result:

```
tester@vubsrv2004:~$ ls -al /srv/Public | grep fromWin10
drwxrwxr-x 2 tester tester 4096 Aug 12 13:15 fromWin10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester    0 Aug 12 13:18 fromWin10.txt
```

Notes:

Per Nmath's comment above this will only work if the target folder is mask-able and mode-able meaning it has to reside on a Linux filesystem.

If it's on a Windows filesystem like fat32 or ntfs you need to modify the umask ( or dmask / fmask ) operatives in your fstab mount of the partition that holds this shared folder.

Comment: Thank you Morbius1.  I tried your solution with "force user = myuser", but I still got drwxr-xr-x.  I found this solution which worked: https://superuser.com/questions/274793/creating-a-samba-share-where-everyone-has-write-access.  The line that worked is "force directory mode = 2775"